# Updating data from a mySQL database using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

Hello everybody and thanks for reading my post.
I am new to NodeJS and Sequelize and I'm building a website on MVC with NodeJS, Express and Sequelize.

I have a pug file called "list" that gives me a list of categories with a button "modify category" next to each category.
On clicking that button, I want to be sent to a page (modify.pug) that let me change the title and description of the category.
Then I want to validate and return to the "list" view to see the updated page.

I read the Sequelize docs but I can't seem to get how to update data.

Here is my controller code :

```
      update(req, res) {
    db.Categories.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(category => {
        return category.update();
      })
      .then(() => {
        res.send("/categories/modify/:id");
      });
  }
}
module.exports = CategoriesController;
```

This gives me an error : it can't find the page.
Thank you for any help you can give me.

Have a good day,

Comment: You need to change `update` for `updateAttributes` and send as parameter the object with the new data.